# C# direct to another page

Tags: c#, redirect, authentication

I have a login form, and when I press in the correct password for it I want it to take me to another page that I have done, how do I make this possible? Ive done this with c# in a windows for appliction

Comment: What kind of application are you doing? Web? ASP.NET?

Comment: I really dont know, Im pretty new to programming but im using visual c# express 2010 and have created the login page and the start page in a simple windows form application

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Forms applications, you can use with [`.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) method.

```
Form targetform = new Form();
targetform.Show();
```

If you are using ASP.NET Web applications, you can use with [`Response.Redirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

```
Response.Redirect("targetpage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of the "other page" (let's call it MainForm) and `.Show()` it:

```
var mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.Show();
```

Comment: hmm okey, but where should i write that code? Inside of the button i created where the if statement is or anywhere else?

Comment: @JessicaLopez - inside the `if` where you validated the login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
 new Form2().Show();
```